# How to achieve partial database backups in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

What would be the best strategy to do database backups?

I am thinking to have 1 main database backup, and partial backups like this:

- 1 main DB file, each time backup is done it appends to this main DB file
- each day backup is done it creates partial database backup with date (this partial actually ads to main DB file)

Which makes structure:

```
/DB_Backup/  
/DB_Backup/Main_Backup.mdf  10GB  
/DB_Backup/20150105_Partial.mdf  200MB  
/DB_Backup/20150104_Partial.mdf  134MB  
/DB_Backup/20150103_Partial.mdf  23 MB  
/DB_Backup/20150102_Partial.mdf  230MB
```

etc..

Comment: Not in any way, shape or form ***programming-related*** --> this should be asked on [dba.stackexchange.com](http://dba.stackexchange.com) instead - voting to move

Comment: 200MB, 134MB, 23MB, 230MB, dont you think you are making your life difficult for a very few MBs here, why not just take a differential backup? You have taken a full backup, just take a differentials backup instead of the partial backup and it should make your backup/restore/recovery strategy more safe and simple.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I needed:

> SET STATISTICS IO ON SET STATISTICS TIME ON
>
> BACKUP DATABASE ReportServer TO
>   DISK =
>   'D:\DBBackups\ReportServer\ReportServer_Split1.bak' ,
>   DISK =
>   'D:\DBBackups\ReportServer\ReportServer_Split2.bak' ,
>   DISK =
>   'D:\DBBackups\ReportServer\ReportServer_Split3.bak'
>
> SET STATISTICS IO OFF SET STATISTICS TIME OFF

More here: [enter link description here](http://beyondrelational.com/modules/2/blogs/88/posts/10153/sql-server-split-database-full-backup-to-multiple-files.aspx)